# Will such a stored procedure cause deadlock?

Tags: sql-server-2008, deadlock

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I am wondering whether this stored procedure causes deadlock if executed by multiple threads at the same time? Another question is -- is it best practices we define begin and end transaction inside of the stored procedure, or defining begin and end transaction from client code (e.g. ADO.Net code)?

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[FooProc]    
(  
 @Param1 int 
 ,@Param2 int  
 ,@Param3 int  
)    
AS    

DELETE FooTable WHERE  Param1 = @Param1     

INSERT INTO FooTable    
 (  
 Param1  
 ,Param2  
 ,Param3  
  )    
 VALUES    
 (  
 @Param1  
 ,@Param2  
 ,@Param3  
  )    

DECLARE @ID bigint    
 SET @ID = ISNULL(@@Identity,-1)    
 IF @ID > 0    
 BEGIN    
      SELECT IdentityStr FROM FooTable WHERE ID = @ID 
 END
```

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Will MERGE do what you need in SQL 2008? Also definitely @@Identity should be avoided. Use SCOPE_IDENTIY

Comment: Yes, I am currently analyzing some issues with legacy code and I need to analyze if deadlock is caused by this store procedure. Any ideas or comments about my original question?

Comment: " @@Identity should be avoided" -- why?

Comment: @@IDENTITY gives the latest identity value, if there is a trigger, you get the identity from that and not from the INSERT in your local scope.  SCOPE_IDENTITY() gives the identity value from your local scope. use profiler and deadlock graph to pinpoint what procedures are involved in deadlocks.

Comment: @George2 - How many records will typically be deleted by `DELETE FooTable WHERE  Param1 = @Param1`? and is there an index on `Param1`? If it needs to get quite a few locks then deadlock could definitely occur in a manner similar to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945135/i-have-data-about-deadlocks-but-i-cant-understand-why-they-occur. As KM suggests setting up a trace to get the deadlock graph will be much more productive.

Comment: Param1 has index but why it matters the count of records to be deleted for deadlock? And what happens if Param1 has no index?

Comment: @George2 the way I was reasoning is the greater the number of records affected the more locks there will be and the less granular they will be.

Comment: "affected the more locks there will be and the less granular they will be" -- why it impacts whether deadlock will happen or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have given *could* cause deadlock. Even if the stored procedure purely consisted of the following statement deadlock could occur.

```
   DELETE FooTable WHERE  Param1 = @Param1
```

Depending upon the exact table definition and indexes available (which you have left out of your question).

Comment: Why consisting of this delete statement will cause deadlock? Any more details? I want to learn why it matters whether there is index on Param1 for deadlock?

Comment: Well the way I was thinking was suppose that invocation 1 of the stored procedure ends up getting page locks on pages x,y,z but needs page a. Invocation 2 of the stored procedure ends up getting page locks on pages a,b,c but needs page x then deadlock would ensue.

Comment: Can you show me sample in my context please? :-) e.g. in the delete statement, page x,y,z and a, b, c are for what page? Why a single delete statement will involve so many pages?

Comment: @George2 We have no idea how many pages will be affected by it as you haven't told us!

Comment: If only one record and Param1 is index, what will happen? And if more than one record will be impacted and Param1 is not indexed, what will happen? I do not want to solve this issue itself, but want to learn from you guru guys how to analyze this deadlock issue in different scenarios?

Comment: I am most definitely not a deadlock guru! Check out 
Remus Rusanu's posts for that http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A105929+deadlock

Comment: I did not find similar scenarios to my case, like why a single delete statement (as you quoted) will cause deadlock?

Comment: single delete statement or single delete record? If the latter then I can't construct a scenario either where it would happen. If the former then the earlier example I gave would do it (maybe relying on a parallel execution plan just to ensure that the locks weren't issued in a linear order).

Comment: Sorry Martin, the question is not very clear. Please discuss here, which I had a more clearer description.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981121/why-single-sql-delete-statement-will-cause-deadlock

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable way to answer your question is to [run your own stress tests](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/close-those-loopholes-stress-test-those-stored-procedures/)

Comment: Sorry Alex, the question is not very clear. Please discuss here, which I had a more clearer description.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981121/why-single-sql-delete-statement-will-cause-deadlock